# Copy Pasting Charts Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts, copy, paste

I am having a problem here with my VBA code.

This is the first code I am writing in VBA.
Basically I want it to check a condition (Value of cell F7 in sheet2), and based on that I would like to paste one of two charts in sheet2.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


CommandButton1.Caption = "Stock Size Range"
CommandButton1.BackColor = 0
CommandButton1.ForeColor = 16777215

'Clear the chart area
 Charts("Chart41").ChartArea.Clear


If Sheets("sheet2").Range("F7") = 1 Then 'Aluminum Material


    Sheets("sheet3").ChartObjects("Chart666").Select
    Sheets("sheet3").ChartObjects("Chart666").Copy
    ChartObjects("Chart41").Paste

    Else

    Sheets("sheet4").ChartObjects("Chart888").Select
    Sheets("sheet4").ChartObjects("Chart888").Copy
    ChartObjects("Chart41").Paste

End If

End Sub
```

Thing is,, when I click on the command button, it gives me a Run-Time error "9": Subscript out of range and it points to the line ( Charts("Chart41").ChartArea.Clear)

Thank you,

Comment: `ChartObjects("Chart41").Chart.ChartArea.Clear`

Comment: Thanks, it says the item with the specified name was not found,, I am pretty sure I changed the name.. What do you think?

Comment: @TimWilliams I managed to make it work. Can you please tell me why my original code did not work?

Comment: A Chart object can either be a Chart sheet, or if it's hosted on a regular worksheet it will be contained in a `ChartObject` - on a worksheet it's the `ChartObject` which has a name, not the Chart.

Comment: One more questions, apparently the line  [ Sheets("sheet1").ChartObjects("chart41").Chart.ChartArea.Clear] ends up deleting the whole chart,, so then when the code wants to paste another chart on Chart41, it can not find it because that line deleted it away!! @TimWilliams

Comment: Any new development?

Answer (score 3):

(Sorry but I do not have enough reputation to write a comment and ask about more information, so I will do my best!)

Hello!

Maybe you need to go to the desired sheet where the chart will be pasted, create a chart and then associate an ID to it, for example "MyNewChart" (you change the chart ID in the "area" where is written "Node 5" in a red rectangle in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf2Nq.png)

Then in your code, when you need to paste the chart, you can write:

```
Sheets("WriteSheetNameHere").ChartObjects("MyNewChart").Paste
```

HTH ;)

Comment: The code is not working again,, can you please advise?
@RCaetano

Comment: What is the behaviour? Only works the first time or it is another thing? Maybe the best approach would be deleting the existing chart (your chart41), then creating a new one before pasting, assign an id to it and finally paste the chart. This steps should be done each time you needed to execute the macro